# Resize MFC grid control to fit in dialog?

Tags: gridview, mfc, resize

I have created an MFC grid control ([Code Project MFC Grid control 2.27](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8/MFC-Grid-control?msg=5410914#xx5410914xx)) in an MFC dialog `MyDlg` (C++, VS2015, 64-bit Windows 7). The `MyDlg.h` file contains

```
CGridCtrl gridCtrl;
```

and the resource editor was used to add a custom control of type `MFCGridCtrl`. In `MyDlg.cpp`, I am subclassing the control with

```
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_ComponentRatios, gridCtrl);
```

In `MyDlg::OnInitDialog`, I set the number of rows and columns with

```
gridCtrl.SetColumnCount(2);
gridCtrl.SetRowCount(2);
gridCtrl.EnableWindow(TRUE);
```

What I get is the 2 x 2 grid I expect, but the size of the custom control does not match the size of the grid.

The custom control's width is wrong, because setting the column count appears to be leaving space for a scroll bar, which is unnecessary.

The height is unchanged, which is wrong because the custom control is sized for 8 rows, and I'm only using 2 in this example (the actual number of rows required is variable).

How can I get the grid to fill the width of the custom control, and to resize the height of that control to match?

Comment: If you used the `CGridCtrl` instead it has a `ExpandColumnsToFit` method.

Comment: If you want to resize the control itself, you can use SetWindowPos(), but there are other things to take into account.  What should be its maximum size? Is the containing dialog resizable? If you want to control its width, what should be the min, max, individual column widths?

Comment: I used MoveWindow to set the control's overall size. The number of cells and their dimensions are fixed, and known at the time the dialog is created. The dialog is not resizable, but even if it were, the control would not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand you question you expect that the grid resizes itself to fit its contents? If so, this isn't a feature of the grid control.

The grid control shows scroll bars only if needed. Unneeded space is shown in a dark gray color. You can expand columns and rows with the function `CGridCtrl::ExpandToFit` to remove all scrollbars, if they are really not needed.

This function also takes care that all grid cells cover the complete controls client space.

Comment: ExpandToFit was just what I needed. What I found was that the control always allowed space for the scroll bars, although it was just dark if they weren't needed. And, I am using MoveWindow to resize the control itself.